# error 404 installing google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I had problems with Google Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 so I uninstalled it. Now, when I'm trying to install the 32bit version from the google website, I keep getting an error 404. I have tried other suggestions from other questions asked here but none of them work. I either get the same error in the terminal or:

```
Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

I'm not a computer programmer so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help, please?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Google have stoped support for Chrome in 32-bit linux distros.

> In a double-whammy, March will also see Google Chrome stop supporting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (which will receive critical and security bug fixes from Canonical until mid 2017).From this March only 64-bit versions of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (or later) will receive new versions of the browser from Google .
>   [Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/01/google-chrome-linux-32-bit-discontinued)

You should try Chromium or Opera of other browser Or
You should Install Ubuntu 64-bit.