# How do I install Adobe Flash Player on Gnome 3.4.2?

Tags: gnome, flash, adobe

I've tried many things that I've seen on this page but I always get some error messages, someone help!

Thanks to this page I was able to solve things on this tablet, like watching videos on youtube on fullscreen and making them sound, also being able to watch videos on facebook and make them sound right, now I need the latest adobe flash player but I can't install it, neither can I install google chrome. Someone please help!

Comment: "Many things"what exactly have you tried? "Get some error messages"what error messages do you get? What Ubuntu release are you using? Please consider edit your question.

Comment: Flash player is not available for Firefox. Chrome does has it.

Comment: I'm new to all these debian stuff so I don't know what I have or how to fix things, I have a tablet that come with this gnome 3.4.2 and debian wheezy that's all. I really need help please!

Comment: I've tried random codes and they made my tablet work better, now i just need the latest adobe flash player. Also I'd like to install google chrome but I get errors. I'm using chromium as my browser. Please help!

Comment: Questions on Debian should be asked at [unix.se].

Comment: IS is os 32bit/64bit??.For 32 bit support for chrome has been removed http://askubuntu.com/questions/742592/error-404-installing-google-chrome/742606#742606

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution is right here :

https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/flashplayer

Personally, in the past, to solve your problem, I had to extract and paste  **libflashplayer.so** in the right place (in the case of Chromium browser for example).